# Json javascript parsing

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json output, I want to parse it and retrieve values of lat and lng. Please help me.

```
 {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Annegatan",
               "short_name" : "Annegatan",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Helsinki",
               "short_name" : "Helsinki",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Finland",
               "short_name" : "FI",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Annegatan, Helsinki, Finland",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 60.17088090,
                  "lng" : 24.94279590
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 60.16266270,
                  "lng" : 24.93114440
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 60.16693210,
               "lng" : 24.93683020
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 60.17088090,
                  "lng" : 24.94279590
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 60.16266270,
                  "lng" : 24.93114440
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Please help me in parsing this and get corresponding latitude and longitude. Get me "location" : {
                   "lat" : 60.16693210,
                   "lng" : 24.93683020
                },
lat long if possible.

Comment: `var obj = {.....};
obj.result[0].location.lat;
obj.result[0].location.lng`

Comment: Got error Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined??

Comment: Let obj be my json response. Then how can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a JSON string, you can use `JSON.parse()` (depending on your browser and version)

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSONstring);
```

On older browsers you can use `eval()` instead

```
var obj = eval(yourJSONstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

**[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/aGXyL/)**

```
var obj = {..............} // assign your json to a variable
```

if its a string then

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{...}');
```

get values like

```
obj.results[0].geometry.location.lat; //60.16693210
obj.results[0].geometry.location.lng; //24.93683020
```

Comment: Got error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined "

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7AjfH/